# Can't output result in bash from an ant command

Tags: bash, ant

I am writing a bash script that modifies some config files, runs "ant ear war" as a different user, outputs the return, exits back to the root to continue with the rest of the script. The issue is that the script does not continue after exiting and I don't get an output from "ant ear war".

Thank you for the help.

here is an example

```
#When running the bash script i don't see the output. Maybe it's because I run it as root and switched to another_user. So I tried to outputing result into a variable and into a text file. Both failed
su another_user
cd /usr/empi/MMEMPIV741/
echo $(ant ear war) >> /tmp/empi_install.txt 
varant="$?"
echo 'if zero it's success otherwise it's a failure'

cp /usr/accessmgr/AMV741/bin/am/JBoss/AccessManager.war /usr/jboss/jboss-eap-4.3/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/
cp /usr/empi/MMEMPIV741/person_project/working-dir/dist/* /usr/jboss/jboss-eap-4.3/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/
exit 

#By this time above is exited from another_user and should return to root
echo $varant

echo "http://`hostname`:21080/PersonMasterIndexDQM/flex/login.jsp#"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the commands you want to run in a different user context into a separate script and run that script via

```
su another_user -c /path/to/other.sh
```